# jQuery Masonry and margin-right

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-masonry

I have two columns in a row, the first column has margin right while the second column doesn't have. I want to use the jQuery Masonry with it to remove the empty spaces. However, the margin right doesn't seem to work with the Masonry.

How can I keep same box width and remove the margin after the second box in the row ?

Here's the **HTML:**

```
<div class="list">

    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item no-margin"></div>

    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item no-margin"></div>

    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item no-margin"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.list{
    width: 350px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.item{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: green;
    margin-right: 50px;  
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    float: left;
}

.no-margin{
    margin-right: 0 !important;

}
```

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery('.list').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.item',
});
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/Y7USd/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery Masonry has an option called `gutterWidth`. You should use that to create that extra margin/gutter between elements.

In your fiddle, you've also missed out to include `modernizr-transitions.js`.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/shodaburp/T3FLr/